# Conditional RedirectMatch based on IP

Tags: htaccess, redirects

How do I use this `RedirectMatch` with limiting by IP address?

This is what I have right now, and it works as is:

```
RewriteRule ^dir.*$ http://www.mysite.org/otherdir/ [R=302,L]
```

I want this to work only if *not* accessed from two different IP addresses. A visit from any other IP address should execute this code in my *.htaccess*.

**Edit:**
Exact code as it appears in my *.htaccess* file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx\.xxx\.xxx\.x    #masked on purpose
RewriteRule ^dir.*$ http://www.mysite.org/otherdir/ [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Edit 2:**
I am now using this in my .htaccess file
    `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1`
    `RewriteRule ^conference - [F]`

This works on my local machine, but if I switch to my external IP address, it's completely ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got this to work (sort of). Here's my final code

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.456.789.0
RewriteRule ^secretdir- [F]
```

I removed the escaping of the periods, and now it seems to work with my external IP address. I'm not sure if that's what is actually causing the problem, but now it works.

I say that it sort of works because (1) it's not redirecting to the dir I want it to, and (2) it's returning a 403 status. I'm almost ready to take `/secretdir` live, so I wish I could return a 302 status.

I hope this helps anyone who runs in to a bizarre problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add conditions to your match, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123\.123\.123\.123 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123\.123\.123\.124
RedirectMatch 302 ^/mydir/.*$ http://mysite.org/myotherdir
```

Obviously, replace the `123` stuff with the actual IP addresses in question, remembering to escape the dots, as shown.

Comment: Hi dflock - that doesn't seem to work. I'm still redirected to the other dir even though I'm accessing it from one of the IPs in my directive. I've updated my question with what I exactly have in my htaccess.

Comment: Hmmm. That should work. I've updated the answer a bit - could you try it again?

Comment: I also added `RewriteLogLevel 9` in, which will add re-write debugging information to the Apache log file for that site - what does it say?

Comment: WHen I add this, my site throws a 500 error, and the message is: RewriteLog not allowed here

Comment: Oooops, sorry my mistake - RewriteLogLevel has been deprecated in favour of `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8` where trace# is the level of logging. See here for more details: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: Still have the same problem with same error. Am I not able to use this in a .htaccess file? My hosting provider does not allow accesss to the apache config file.

Comment: No, LogLevel can only be used in server config or virtualhost configs, not .htaccess, you'll have to take it out on a shared host, sorry.

Comment: ok, thanks. any other thought as to why the RewriteCond doesn't work? The RedirectMatch obviously does..

Comment: I just tried this setup on one of my sites and it works perfectly. Are you 100% sure that you're testing for the correct IP addresses? Remember that the publicly visible IP address might be different that the locally visible one - do this to see what your public IP is: https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip+address - if that's not it, I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: yea, I am using my public Ip that is static. Thanks for the help; I'll ask around other places, and if I come across a solution to my problem, I'll post it here.

Comment: Just wanted to give some more information here: I verified using <?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?> that I have the correct IP address in the rewrite condition. For some reason, it's completely ignored. When I use 127.0.0.1 it sort of works. It doesn't redirect me.